# Magento 2 : Change Number of Items Per Row set From Admin for Different Categories

Tags: magento2, admin, category

I'm trying to change number of items per row in product listing page.

I want to set different items per row for differant categories from: **"admin panel > category > design > layout update xml"**

Magento 1, Like this : < action method="setColumnCount"> < count> 4 < /count>< /action>

Above code I want to use in magento 2.

Comment: Jimit could you please check my solution and confirm whether or not it is working for you. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaFlood  yes, it's working.

Comment: Excellent. Can you please accept my answer?

Comment: i have accept ...............

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that most of your questions have answers but haven't been accepted. If any of them are working it'd be great if you could accept them. It helps the community to find solutions more easily.. and it also helps the reputation of the people who help you.

Comment: i haven't use your answer, i have already solved this issue before you answer approx 1.5 year ago.

Comment: Ok. I didn't mean this one specifically, I just meant in general. Though, if you answer your own problem, it would help the community even more if you could answer it here and then you can accept your own answer, I think after 48 hours.

Comment: I'm not trying to criticise you mate, just making some suggestions that would boost the stats of your account and help out the stack exchange search engines.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with a similar problem. My aim was to display no more than 4 products per row, using a custom theme which inherits from the blank theme.

In  order to edit columns for regular catalog pages, you must copy the following directory:

> [install_dir]/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less

to your theme directory:

> [install_dir]/app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less

If you would like to edit the widget columns as well, then you copy the following:

> [install_dir]/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_widgets.less

to your theme directory:

> [install_dir]/app/design/frontend/[vendor_name]/[theme_name]/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/_widgets.less

and adjust styles accordingly.

Here is an example of the CSS I used to neatly display 4 columns per row:

```
.page-layout-1column .block.widget .products-grid .product-item {
    margin-left: calc(~'(100% - 5 * (100%/5)) / 4');
    width: 100%/4;

    &:nth-child(4n + 1) {
        margin-left: calc(~'(100% - 5 * (100%/5)) / 4');
    }

    &:nth-child(5n + 1) {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

I won't display the whole code, because you'll need to adjust it for your particular needs.

Comment: You suggestion is correct but not sure every them have same code or design so do according to your theme .less

Comment: Yes I agree. Hence I specified that this is specific to the blank theme and should be adjusted to suit the person's individual needs.

Answer (score -3):

You can show different number of item per category by using following code(make sure that you use reference block name correctly for list(setDefaultListPerPage) and grid view(setDefaultGridPerPage)):-

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
          <action method="setDefaultListPerPage">
                 <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">4</argument>
          </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Check the setting in admin panel 
"Products per Page on List Allowed Values" OR "Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values" on catalog configuration should that the limit value you are assigning to category.

Check out this url for more.([link](http://www.w3solver.com/magento-2-show-different-number-of-product-for-every-category-page/))

Comment: I have check above code with two different magento 2 setup , but it's not working.

Comment: Not sure why this is not working, i tried on Magento 2.1.5 and it works perfectly fine. Is it giving some error. or just not working

Comment: I'm try to update : <argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>, it's not giving any error and showing default number of items per row.

Comment: Also the limit value that you are adding should also be added in admin panel under configuration > catalog > catalog > storefront > Products per Page on List Allowed Values

Comment: I have update Products per Page on List Allowed Values  = 2,4,6,8,10, but still not working.

I think this setting will apply for all categories , i do not want to apply for all categories.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of frontend and code which u are adding and admin configuration setting

Comment: I have tested this thrice and it works perfectly fine. Products per Page on List Allowed Values will tell magento which limit can be considered else default will be picked. You must be missing something. Also I tried your code "<argument name="limit" xsi:type="string">2</argument>" but this does not work for my Magento ver. 2.1.5. I get same error not allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57464/discussion-between-arushi-and-jmt).

Comment: Your code is doing something else than is asked in the question. This answer changes how many products are shown in page instead of changing how many products will be in one row (or in other words - how many product columns there will be in page).

Comment: I've just added an answer, if anyone still needs it.