# How to set number of columns in category listing for magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-listing

I want to display 4 columns in the category listing for Magento 2. Means Now products showing 3 columns, Need to change 3 to 4 so Product will show like below

Before

```
Product-1 | Product-2 | Product-3
Product-4 | Product-5 | Product-6
```

Need After

```
Product-1 | Product-2 | Product-3 |Product-4
Product-5 | Product-6 | Product-7 | Product-8
```

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: Please find the solution: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170936/magento-2-change-number-of-items-per-row-set-from-admin-for-different-categori?rq=1

Comment: Are you using blank theme or luma theme?

Comment: Im using sahara paid theme

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify yourcss.less file. By change &:nth-of-type(3n+1) value as per your requirement .
[image]